# What happens when you chsh without a user name?

Tags: chsh

One may:
`sudo chsh -s /bin/sh`
or
`sudo chsh -s /bin/sh user_name`

It is understood that the second command changes the shell for the specified *user_name* but unclear what happens without specifying a *user_name* and where is that reflected?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command without a user changes the root user:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ sudo chsh -s /bin/sh
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/passwd | grep "/bin/sh"
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/sh
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ sudo chsh -s /bin/bash
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/passwd | grep "/bin/bash"
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

Comment: So it is essentially like typing `sudo chsh -s /bin/bash root` ?

Comment: @AturSams Correct, it is the same as that.  To run the command on your own user, sudo is not needed and neither is your username.

Comment: Specifically, using `sudo` is a bad idea: normal users are limited to shells listed in `/etc/shells`, so users cannot accidentally lock themselves out by switching to something that isn't a working shell. As root, you can set anything, including something that doesn't work.

Comment: The reason `sudo chsh` changes the shell for root is that `sudo` switches to root, and `chsh` changes the shell of the current user.

Comment: @SimonRichter Thanks for clarifying. :)

Comment: Which makes quite a bit of sense; `chsh` without `sudo` would change the user's own shell. I'm kind of disappointed that on too many linux systems, `chsh` without `sudo` yields an error.